# Change a single view in a state with ui-router in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this simple webapp

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view="leftbar"></div>
<div ui-view="rightbar"></div>
```

**bar.html**

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

**hello.html**

```
Hello!
```

**app.js**

```
..
.state('app',{
   views: {
     leftbar: {templateUrl: "bar.html"},
     rightbar: {templateUrl: "bar.html"}
   }
})
.state('app.rightHello',{
 /* ??????*/)}
```

What should I put in the `app.rightHello` state to let it change just the `rightbar`?
How can I change, with a `state`, just a single view, without touching the other?

Actually I can do that just with a `no name view`, updated by default with a `templateUrl` used in the state.